# ASP.net email attachment as body of the email using pre prepared HTML template

Tags: asp.net, email

I need to send out email attachment as body of the email. It is like sending an E card to someone. I read somewhere that we can do this by using HTML template and passing the values such as {name} etc. Can anyone point me to a tutorial on this or tell me how to do this?

I am submitting a usercontrol and want to pass values captured in the usercontrol to the email attachment.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [`MailDefinition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.maildefinition.aspx) class, which has built-in support for template fields.

```
Dear <%FirstName%>,

blah blah blah <%SomeOtherField%>

etc.
```

Comment: so can I use Html file with images etc instead of mail.txt? Also, where do I store this file and inside the file how will the replacements look like? will it look like {To}?

Comment: ok, so I got it to the point of passing values and receiving emails. So you response help me a lot. I have one more question though, I am using html files and passing values. That works but the only problem is the email shows the whole html code. such as <html> hello value </html>. the mail body itself is not html. It is still taking it as text file. any clues?

Comment: Actually got it all working. thank you so much for the quick help.